# LinkedBlockingQueue with fast contains(Object o) method?

Tags: java, concurrency

In a nutshell, I'm writing an application that needs a `BlockingQueue` implementation that provides both FIFO adds/removes, but also a fast `contains` method, as I'll be calling it a TON.

`LinkedBlockingQueue` gets me most of the way there, but it appears that its `contains` method runs in linear time, as it is based on `AbstractQueue`'s `contains` method.  I didn't see anything in the Java API that seemed to advertise an LBQ with fast `contains` out-of-the-box.

What makes things tougher is, my project is on a really severe time crunch (no, this isn't homework).  I could do a quick-and-dirty LBQ extension with a `HashSet` underneath for fast `contains`, but I'm still going to have to test it, which could eat up a significant amount of man-hours.  I'm wondering if there are any trusted/well-tested libraries out there that provide a `LinkedBlockingQueue` extension with a `contains` method that runs in O(1) time...?  If not, any other suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Um... just how many man hours do you expect it to take to test a queue with an extra hash set? Call me Mr Crazy-Dangerous but it doesn't sound *such* a major job to me...

Comment: You must not work for a government institution then... ;)

Comment: So *that's* where my tax dollars are going... ;)

Comment: Depends on what country you live in ;)  And hey, I didn't say how many man-hours, I just said "significant", as in, there are other things to be done in a short amount of time on this project.  Just because I work for "a" government doesn't mean I'm a politician ;)

Comment: LinkedBlockingQueue allows for dups so it would need to be a [`HashMultiset`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release02/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/HashMultiset.html) or something similar.

Comment: Yes -- in reality, you'd probably end up with a hashmap of <Item, Count>.

Comment: A dirty way would be to maintain a hashset-like structure in parallel (say a concurrentmap) but to make everything atomic would introduce unnecessary synchronization/contention.

Comment: @asslyias yeah, that's exactly what I'm worried about.  This particular queue is going to be dealing with a lot of throughput, so unnecessary synchronization could become an issue at some point.  I think I'm gonna bite the bullet and do the underlying HashMap approach. If synchronization cost ends up becoming a performance issue, I'll cross that bridge if I get to it.

Comment: If you want to make contains() fast, the trade-off will be slower insertion and removal.

Comment: @wyz contains() will be called many more times than insert() and remove(), so in this case, the trade-off is justified, but you're definitely right about that.

Comment: Why do you want to do contains on a blocking queue? Does your dequeue behaviour depends on its result?

Comment: The enqueue behavior depends on the result.  I need to make sure that the queue contains only one copy of each item I plan on storing.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Thanks again to all who provided input.  I ended up coding my own `HashedLinkedBlockingQueue` implementation.  Getting the synchronization correct by using the decorator pattern proved much more difficult than anticipated.  Adding synchronization to the decorator caused deadlocks to occur under heavy load (particularly, `put(E element)` and `take()` introduced hold-and-wait conditions that previously didn't exist).  When coupled with decreased performance because of unnecessary synchronization, it became apparent that I'd need to spend the time to get it right from scratch.

Performance in `add`/`remove`/`contains` is O(1) but comes with roughly double the synchronization cost of the original `LinkedBlockingQueue` - I say "roughly double" because the LBQ uses two locks - one for inserts and one for removes when the queue size is sufficiently large to allow concurrent modification of head and tail.  My implementation uses a single lock, so removes must wait for adds to complete and vice versa.  Here's the source code for the class - I have tested each method in both multi-threaded and single-threaded modes, but outside of using this class in my own application, I have not come up with a super-complicated, generalized test.  Use at your own risk!  Just because it works in my app doesn't mean there aren't still bugs:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

/**
 * Provides a single-lock queuing algorithm with fast contains(Object o) and
 * remove(Object o), at the expense of higher synchronization cost when
 * compared to {@link LinkedBlockingQueue}.  This queue implementation does not
 * allow for duplicate entries.
 * 
 * <p>Use of this particular {@link BlockingQueue} implementation is encouraged
 * when the cost of calling 
 * <code>{@link BlockingQueue#contains(Object o)}</code> or 
 * <code>{@link BlockingQueue#remove(Object o)}</code> outweighs the throughput
 * benefit if using a {@link LinkedBlockingQueue}.  This queue performs best
 * when few threads require simultaneous access to it.
 * 
 * <p>The basic operations this queue provides and their associated run times
 * are as follows, where <i>n</i> is the number of elements in this queue and
 * <i>m</i> is the number of elements in the specified collection, if any such
 * collection is specified:
 * 
 * <ul>
 * <li><b>add(E element)</b> - <i>O(1)</i></li>
 * <li><b>addAll(Collection<? extends E> c)</b> - <i>O(m)</i></li>
 * <li><b>drainTo(Collection<? extends E> c, int maxElements)</b>
 *  - <i>O(maxElements*O(</i><code>c.add(Object o)</code><i>))</i></li>
 * <li><b>contains(E element)</b> - <i>O(1)</i></li>
 * <li><b>offer(E element)</b> - <i>O(1)</i></li>
 * <li><b>poll()</b> - <i>O(1)</i></li>
 * <li><b>remove(E element)</b> - <i>O(1)</i></li>
 * <li><b>removeAll(Collection<? extends E> c)</b> - <i>O(m)</i></li>
 * <li><b>retainAll(Collection<? extends E> c)</b> - <i>O(n*O(
 *  </i><code>c.contains(Object o)</code><i>))</i></li>
 * </ul>
 * 
 * @param <E> type of element this queue will handle.  It is strongly
 * recommended that the underlying element overrides <code>hashCode()</code> 
 * and <code>equals(Object o)</code> in an efficient manner.
 * 
 * @author CodeBlind
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class HashedLinkedBlockingQueue<E> implements BlockingQueue<E>{
    /** Polling removes the head, offering adds to the tail. */
    private Node head, tail;
    /** Required for constant-time lookups and removals. */
    private HashMap<E,Node> contents;
    /** Allows the user to artificially limit the capacity of this queue. */
    private final int maxCapacity;

    //Constructors: -----------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * Creates an empty queue with max capacity equal to
     * {@link Integer#MAX_VALUE}.
     */
    public HashedLinkedBlockingQueue(){ this(null,Integer.MAX_VALUE); }

    /**
     * Creates an empty queue with max capacity equals to the specified value.
     * @param capacity (1 to {@link Integer#MAX_VALUE})
     */
    public HashedLinkedBlockingQueue(int capacity){
        this(null,Math.max(1,capacity)); 
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new queue and initializes it to the contents of the specified
     * collection, queued in the order returned by its iterator, with a max
     * capacity of {@link Integer#MAX_VALUE}.
     * @param c collection of elements to add
     */
    public HashedLinkedBlockingQueue(Collection<? extends E> c){
        this(c,Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new queue and initializes it to the contents of the specified
     * collection, queued in the order returned by its iterator, with a max
     * capacity equal to the specified value.
     * @param c collection of elements to add
     * @param capacity (1 to {@link Integer#MAX_VALUE})
     */
    public HashedLinkedBlockingQueue(Collection<? extends E> c, int capacity){
        maxCapacity = capacity;
        contents = new HashMap<E,Node>();

        if(c == null || c.isEmpty()){
            head = null;
            tail = null;
        }
        else for(E e : c) enqueue(e);
    }

    //Private helper methods: -------------------------------------------------

    private E dequeue(){
        if(contents.isEmpty()) return null;

        Node n = head;
        contents.remove(n.element);

        if(contents.isEmpty()){
            head = null;
            tail = null;
        }
        else{
            head.next.prev = null;
            head = head.next;
            n.next = null;
        }

        return n.element;
    }

    private void enqueue(E e){
        if(contents.containsKey(e)) return;

        Node n = new Node(e);
        if(contents.isEmpty()){
            head = n;
            tail = n;
        }
        else{
            tail.next = n;
            n.prev = tail;
            tail = n;
        }

        contents.put(e,n);
    }

    private void removeNode(Node n, boolean notify){
        if(n == null) return;
        if(n == head) dequeue();
        else if(n == tail){
            tail.prev.next = null;
            tail = tail.prev;
            n.prev = null;
        }
        else{
            n.prev.next = n.next;
            n.next.prev = n.prev;
            n.prev = null;
            n.next = null;
        }

        contents.remove(n.element);
        if(notify) synchronized(this){ contents.notifyAll(); }
    }

    //Public instance methods: ------------------------------------------------

    public void print(){
        Node n = head;
        int i = 1;
        while(n != null){
            System.out.println(i+": "+n);
            n = n.next;
            i++;
        }
    }

    //Overridden methods: -----------------------------------------------------

    @Override
    public boolean add(E e){
        synchronized(this){
            if(remainingCapacity() < 1) throw new IllegalStateException();
            enqueue(e);
            contents.notifyAll();
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends E> c){
        boolean changed = true;
        synchronized(this){
            for(E e : c){
                if(remainingCapacity() < 1) throw new IllegalStateException();
                enqueue(e);
            }

            contents.notifyAll();
        }
        return changed;
    }

    @Override
    public void clear(){
        synchronized(this){
            if(isEmpty()) return;
            head = null;
            tail = null;
            contents.clear();
            contents.notifyAll();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean contains(Object o){
        synchronized(this){ return contents.containsKey(o); }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean containsAll(Collection<?> c) {
        synchronized(this){
            for(Object o : c) if(!contents.containsKey(o)) return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int drainTo(Collection<? super E> c) {
        return drainTo(c,maxCapacity);
    }

    @Override
    public int drainTo(Collection<? super E> c, int maxElements) {
        if(this == c) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        int transferred = 0;

        synchronized(this){
            while(!isEmpty() && transferred < maxElements)
                if(c.add(dequeue())) transferred++;
            if(transferred > 0) contents.notifyAll();
        }

        return transferred;
    }

    @Override
    public E element(){
        E e = peek();
        if(e == null) throw new IllegalStateException();
        return e;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        synchronized(this){ return contents.isEmpty(); }
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<E> iterator(){ return new Itr(); }

    @Override
    public boolean offer(E e){
        synchronized(this){
            if(contents.containsKey(e)) return false;
            enqueue(e);
            contents.notifyAll();
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean offer(E e, long timeout, TimeUnit unit)
            throws InterruptedException{
        long remainingSleep = -1;
        long millis = unit.toMillis(timeout);
        long methodCalled = System.currentTimeMillis();

        synchronized(this){
            while((remainingSleep = 
                    (methodCalled+millis)-System.currentTimeMillis()) > 0 &&
                    (remainingCapacity() < 1 || contents.containsKey(e))){
                contents.wait(remainingSleep);
            }

            if(remainingSleep < 1) return false;
            enqueue(e);
            contents.notifyAll();
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public E peek(){
        synchronized(this){ return (head != null) ? head.element : null; }
    }

    @Override
    public E poll(){
        synchronized(this){
            E e = dequeue();
            if(e != null) contents.notifyAll();
            return e;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public E poll(long timeout, TimeUnit unit) throws InterruptedException{
        E e = null;
        long remainingSleep = -1;
        long millis = unit.toMillis(timeout);
        long methodCalled = System.currentTimeMillis();

        synchronized(this){
            e = dequeue();

            while(e == null && (remainingSleep = (methodCalled+millis)-
                    System.currentTimeMillis()) > 0){
                contents.wait(remainingSleep);
                e = dequeue();
            }

            if(e == null) e = dequeue();
            if(e != null) contents.notifyAll();
        }

        return e;
    }

    @Override
    public void put(E e) throws InterruptedException{
        synchronized(this){
            while(remainingCapacity() < 1) contents.wait();
            enqueue(e);
            contents.notifyAll();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int remainingCapacity(){ return maxCapacity-size(); }

    @Override
    public E remove(){
        E e = poll();
        if(e == null) throw new IllegalStateException();
        return e;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean remove(Object o){
        synchronized(this){
            Node n = contents.get(o);
            if(n == null) return false;
            removeNode(n,true);
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean removeAll(Collection<?> c){
        if(this == c){
            synchronized(this){
                if(isEmpty()){
                    clear();
                    return true;
                }
            }

            return false;
        }

        boolean changed = false;

        synchronized(this){
            for(Object o : c){
                Node n = contents.get(o);
                if(n == null) continue;
                removeNode(n,false);
                changed = true;
            }

            if(changed) contents.notifyAll();
        }

        return changed;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean retainAll(Collection<?> c){
        boolean changed = false;
        if(this == c) return changed;

        synchronized(this){
            for(E e : new LinkedList<E>(contents.keySet())){
                if(!c.contains(e)){
                    Node n = contents.get(e);
                    if(n != null){
                        removeNode(n,false);
                        changed = true;
                    }
                }
            }

            if(changed) contents.notifyAll();
        }

        return changed;
    }

    @Override
    public int size(){ synchronized(this){ return contents.size(); }}

    @Override
    public E take() throws InterruptedException{
        synchronized(this){
            while(contents.isEmpty()) contents.wait();
            return dequeue();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Object[] toArray(){
        synchronized(this){ return toArray(new Object[size()]); }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public <T> T[] toArray(T[] a) {
        synchronized(this){
            //Estimate size of array; be prepared to see more or fewer elements
            int size = size();
            T[] r = a.length >= size ? a :
                (T[])java.lang.reflect.Array
                .newInstance(a.getClass().getComponentType(), size);
            Iterator<E> it = iterator();

            for (int i = 0; i < r.length; i++) {
                if (! it.hasNext()) { // fewer elements than expected
                    if (a != r)
                        return Arrays.copyOf(r, i);
                    r[i] = null; // null-terminate
                    return r;
                }
                r[i] = (T)it.next();
            }
            return it.hasNext() ? finishToArray(r, it) : r;
        }
    }

    //Static helper methods: --------------------------------------------------

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private static <T> T[] finishToArray(T[] r, Iterator<?> it) {
        int i = r.length;

        while (it.hasNext()) {
            int cap = r.length;
            if (i == cap) {
                int newCap = ((cap / 2) + 1) * 3;
                if (newCap <= cap) { // integer overflow
                    if (cap == Integer.MAX_VALUE)
                        throw new OutOfMemoryError
                        ("Required array size too large");
                    newCap = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
                }
                r = Arrays.copyOf(r, newCap);
            }
            r[i++] = (T)it.next();
        }
        // trim if overallocated
        return (i == r.length) ? r : Arrays.copyOf(r, i);
    }

    //Private inner classes: --------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * Provides a weak iterator that doesn't check for concurrent modification
     * but also fails elegantly.  A race condition exists when simultaneously
     * iterating over the queue while the queue is being modified, but this is
     * allowable per the Java specification for Iterators.
     * @author CodeBlind
     */
    private class Itr implements Iterator<E>{
        private Node current;
        private E currentElement;

        private Itr(){
            synchronized(HashedLinkedBlockingQueue.this){
                current = head;
                if(current != null) currentElement = current.element;
                else currentElement = null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext(){
            return currentElement != null;
        }

        @Override
        public E next(){
            if(currentElement == null) throw new NoSuchElementException();

            synchronized(HashedLinkedBlockingQueue.this){
                E e = currentElement;

                current = current.next;
                if(current == null || !contents.containsKey(current.element)){
                    current = null;
                    currentElement = null;
                }
                else currentElement = current.element;

                return e;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void remove(){
            synchronized(HashedLinkedBlockingQueue.this){
                if(current == null || !contents.containsKey(current.element))
                    throw new NoSuchElementException();

                Node n = current;
                current = current.next;
                if(current != null && contents.containsKey(current.element))
                    currentElement = current.element;
                else currentElement = null;

                removeNode(n,true);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * This class provides a simple implementation for a node in a double-
     * linked list.  It supports constant-time, in-place removals.
     * @author CodeBlind
     */
    private class Node{
        private Node(E e){
            element = e;
            prev = null;
            next = null;
        }

        private E element;
        private Node prev, next;

        @Override
        public String toString(){
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Node[prev.element=");
            if(prev == null) sb.append("null,element=");
            else sb.append(prev.element+",element=");
            sb.append(element+",next.element=");
            if(next == null) sb.append("null]");
            else sb.append(next.element+"]");
            return sb.toString();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As others already said, using a hash-based structure is the solution.
I don't see any implementation on the Java Collection API.

But you can create a HashBlockingQueue decorator easily with the Guava class ForwardingBlockingQueue