# Thread-safe FIFO queue with unique items and thread pool

Tags: java, multithreading

I have to manage scheduled file replications in a system. The file replications are scheduled by users and I need to restrict the amount of system resources used during replication. The amount of time that each replication may take is not defined (i.e. a replication may be scheduled to run every 15 minutes and the previous run may still be running when the next run is due) and a replication should not be queued if it's already queued or running.

I have a scheduler that periodically checks for due file replications and, for each one, (1) add it to a blocking queue if it is not queued nor running or (2) drop it otherwise.

```
private final Object scheduledReplicationsLock = new Object();
private final BlockingQueue<Replication> replicationQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
private final Set<Long> queuedReplicationIds = new HashSet<>();
private final Set<Long> runningReplicationIds = new HashSet<>();

public boolean add(Replication replication) {

    synchronized (scheduledReplicationsLock) {
        // If the replication job is either still executing or is already queued, do not add it.
        if (queuedReplicationIds.contains(replication.id) || runningReplicationIds.contains(replication.id)) {
            return false;
        }
        replicationQueue.add(replication)
        queuedReplicationIds.add(replication.id);
    }
```

I also have a pool of threads that waits until there is a replication in the queue and executes it. Below is the main method of each thread in the thread pool:

```
public void run() {
    while (True) {
        Replication replication = null;
        synchronized (scheduledReplicationsLock) {
            // This will block until a replication job is ready to be run or the current thread is interrupted.
            replication = replicationQueue.take();

            // Move the ID value out of the queued set and into the active set
            Long replicationId = replication.getId();
            queuedReplicationIds.remove(replicationId);
            runningReplicationIds.add(replicationId);
        }
        executeReplication(replication)
    }
}
```

This code gets into a deadlock because the first thread in the thread poll will get scheduledLock and prevent the scheduler to add replications to the queue. Moving replicationQueue.take() out of the synchronized block will eliminate the deadlock, but then it's possible that a element is removed from the queue and the hash sets are not atomically updated with it, which could cause a replication to be incorrectly dropped.

Should I use BlockingQueue.poll() and release the lock + sleep if the queue is empty instead of using BlockingQueue.take() ?

Fixes to the current solution or other solutions that meet the requirements are welcome.

Comment: queuedReplicationIds looks like de duplicate of replicationQueue. I don't know why You need it in your algorithm, but with remove it  the lock could be avoidable. - If changing the algorithmy is not the solution, maybe yield/sleep could be your solution, but it seems like a workaround to me.

Comment: @pdem queuedReplicationIds has the IDs of the replications in replicationQueue. It's used to speed up checking if a replication is queued, as checking if an element is in a HashSet (amortized time complexity: O(1)) is much faster than doing it in a queue (O(N))

Comment: @AlanEvangelista how many elements do you have an average for the replication and how frequent did you make an synchronization? I assume that time consumption of the queue.contains() will not so critical, but your code will be more simple without additional synchronization and locks and interruptions and so on....

Answer (score 2):

### wait / notify

Keeping your same control flow, instead of blocking on the `BlockingQueue` instance while holding the mutex lock, you can `wait` on notifications for the `scheduledReplicationsLock` forcing the worker thread to release the lock and return to the waiting pool.

Here down a reduced sample of your producer:

```
private final List<Replication> replicationQueue = new LinkedList<>();
private final Set<Long> runningReplicationIds = new HashSet<>();

public boolean add(Replication replication) {
    synchronized (replicationQueue) {
        // If the replication job is either still executing or is already queued, do not add it.
        if (replicationQueue.contains(replication) || runningReplicationIds.contains(replication.id)) {
            return false;
        } else {
            replicationQueue.add(replication);
            replicationQueue.notifyAll();
        }
    }
}
```

The worker `Runnable` would then be updated as follows:

```
public void run() {
    synchronized (replicationQueue) {
        while (true) {
            if (replicationQueue.isEmpty()) {
                scheduledReplicationsLock.wait();
            }
            if (!replicationQueue.isEmpty()) {
                Replication replication = replicationQueue.poll();
                runningReplicationIds.add(replication.getId())
                executeReplication(replication);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### BlockingQueue

Generally you are better off using the `BlockingQueue` to coordinate your producer and replicating worker pool.

The `BlockingQueue` is, as the name implies, blocking by nature and will cause the calling thread to block only if items cannot be pulled / pushed from / to the queue.

Meanwhile, note that you will have to update your running / enqueued state management as you will only synchronizing on the `BlockingQueue` items dropping any constraints. This then will depend on the context, whether this would be acceptable or not.

This way, you would drop all other used mutex(es) and use on the `BlockingQueue` as your synchronization state:

```
private final BlockingQueue<Replication> replicationQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();

public boolean add(Replication replication) {
    // not sure if this is the proper invariant to check as at some point the replication would be neither queued nor running while still have been processed
    if (replicationQueue.contains(replication)) {
        return false;
    }
    // use `put` instead of `add` as this will block waiting for free space
    replicationQueue.put(replication);
    return true;
}
```

The workers will then `take` indefinitely from the `BlockingQueue`:

```
public void run() {
    while (true) {
        Replication replication = replicationQueue.take();
        executeReplication(replication);
    }
}
```

Comment: The downsides of the 2nd approach are that it will allow adding a replication to the queue while it is still running (e.g. if the replication takes 15 mins, but it's scheduled to run every 10 minutes) and that BlockingQueue.contains() has time complexity O(N) while retrieval in a HashSet has amortized time complexity O(1). Besides that, wouldn't the 2nd approach allow insertion of duplicates, as BlockingQueue.contains() and BlockingQueue.put() are not necessarily executed atomically (i.e. there may be a context switch after contains() and before put())?

Answer (score 0):

You no need to use any additional synchronization block if you using BlockingQueue

Quote from docs (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html)

> BlockingQueue implementations are **thread-safe**. All queuing methods achieve their effects **atomically using internal locks** or other forms of concurrency control.

just use something like this

```
public void run() {
    try {
        while (replicationQueue.take()) { //Thread will be wait for the next element in the queue
          Long replicationId = replication.getId();
          queuedReplicationIds.remove(replicationId);
          runningReplicationIds.add(replicationId);
          executeReplication(replication);
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
      //if interrupted while waiting next element
    }
}
```

}

look in javadoc https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html#take()

Or you can use BlockinQueue.pool() with timeout settings

UPD: After discussion, I extend LinkedBlockingQueue with two ConcurrentHashSets and add method afterTake() to remove processed Replicas. You do not need an additional synchronizations outside the queue. Just put replica in the first thread and take it in another, and call afterTake() when replication finished. You need to override other method if you want to use it.

```
package ru.everytag;

import io.vertx.core.impl.ConcurrentHashSet;

import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;

public class TwoPhaseBlockingQueue<E> extends LinkedBlockingQueue<E> {
  private ConcurrentHashSet<E> items = new ConcurrentHashSet<>();
  private ConcurrentHashSet<E> taken = new ConcurrentHashSet<>();

@Override
public void put(E e) throws InterruptedException {
    if (!items.contains(e)) {
        items.add(e);
        super.put(e);
    }
}

public E take() {
    E item = take();

    taken.add(item);
    items.remove(item);

    return item;
}

public void afterTake(E e) {
    if (taken.contains(e)) {
        taken.remove(e);
    } else if (items.contains(e)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Element still in the queue");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: That would allow inconsistencies between the queue and the hash sets, for instance if there is a context switch right after execution enters the loop or after removing the replication ID from the queueReplicationIds set.

Comment: Why do you need the Set of replicationIds? You can use replicationQueue.contains(replication) if you have replication.equals() implementation base on id value.

But it that case may be it would be better for performance to use ArrayBlockingQueue instead of LinkedBlockingQueue.

Comment: For performance. Checking if an element is in a HashSet has O(1) amortized time complexity. Checking if an element is in a queue has O(n).

Comment: Are you sure?

Quote from javadoc of HashSet
>>Returns true if this set contains the specified element. More formally, returns true if and only if this set contains an element e such that (o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e)).

HashSet.contains call HashTable.contains that iterates stored hashes in the table and check equals for each.

Comment: Sorry, but I do not see how that quote contradicts the time complexity I mentioned before.

Comment: I am not sure, that time complexity so important for your case, and it need to be compared with the time consumption of the synchronization blocks, but you can use  HashedLinkedBlockingQueue implementation from this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10841760/linkedblockingqueue-with-fast-containsobject-o-method

Comment: Thanks for the link. My only concern is not only the O(1) time complexity provided by the queuedReplicationIds hash set, but also being able to ignore a replication instead of adding it to the queue if it's running (provided by the runningReplicationIds hash set)

Comment: Where did you find O(1) complexity of HashSet?

Comment: I read the comments in the implementation of HashSet that backed by HashMap and didn't find any clearly mentions of the complexity O(1) it was only in some article in the internet. But I found this comments in the HashMap implementation 
---
     * of tree bins is worthwhile in providing worst-case O(log n)
     * operations when keys either have distinct hashes or are
     * orderable, Thus, performance degrades gracefully under
     * accidental or malicious usages in which hashCode()

Comment: I didn't look into the HashSet implementation, but hashes have amortized time complexity O(1) by definition. All related StackOverflow answers and Internet articles say that applies for HashSet, e.g. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/hashset-in-java/ and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6574916/hashset-look-up-complexity . Regardless of performance, my greatest requirement is making sure that running replications are not added to the queue and I need to keep/check the running replication IDs for that. Synchronizing only on the queue contents is not enough.